# Check if a Popup is being closed Jquery Mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, popup

so i have a little problem i have code like that trying to create a mobile website with jquerymobile...
HTML:

```
<div>
<input type="text" id="first">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="second">
</div>
<button id="testButton">
  Checking
</button>
<div data-role="popup" id="popup"><p>I am a Popup</p></div>
```

js/jquery...

```
var begin = $("#first").val();
var end = $("#second").val();

$(document).on("click","#testButton", function(){

if(begin > end){
$("#popup").popup("open");

$("#second").css({"border": "2px solid red"});
}

})
```

So what i wanna do is, if the inserted value of Begin is greater then the value of End. A Popup should be activated and then **AFTER** the popup is clicked away by the user the End input element should get a red border. 
 I can only make it work that the border and the popup take effect at the same moment the button is clicked and not step by step. Is there a way to check if the popup is closed and then set the border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the popup's **[afterClose event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#event-afterclose)**:

```
$("#popup").on( "popupafterclose", function( event, ui ) {
    $("#second").css({"border": "2px solid red"});
});
```

## **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/grNaGw)**